# how to i get python schedule to loop through my task

Tags: python, schedule

please help me debug this code please. i have list of users which i want them to be doing different task as wanted. i want this users to be able to start this task at a scheduled time but the issue here is i cant loop through the users. if i dont use schedule, the code runs as i want but when i use schedule it only output just one user at that particular time hopefully will output another the next time. please help here, thats my code below

```py
import random
import schedule as s
import time


Activities = ['eating', 'coding', 'praying', 'reading']


class now:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def start(self):

        print('My name is', self.name)

        a = random.choice(Activities)
        if a == 'eating':
            print('i am eating..')
        elif a == 'coding':
            print('I am coding')
        elif a == 'praying':
            print('I am praying')
        else:
            print('I am visit: reading')

user1 = now('king')
user2 = now('chibuike')
user3 = now('ogodo')
user4 = now('kingsley')
user5 = now('sunday')
user6 = now('success')
user7 = now('emeka')
user8 = now('jekwu')
user9 = now('obinna')

all = [user1, user2, user3,user4, user5, user6, user7, user8, user9]
random.shuffle(all)


for i in all:
    s.every().day.at("13:11").do(i.start)
    while True:
       s.run_pending()
```

I want the code to be able to loop through and output all the users with their activities at the scheduled time not just one user at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your while loop above the for loop like this:

```
while True:
    for i in all:
        s.every().day.at("13:45").do(i.start)
        s.run_pending()
```

You may need to add a `time.sleep(1)` after `s.run_pending()` but I have not tested that.

Comment: Thanks but this wasn't able to solve my problem

Comment: What was the output after you made this change and how was it not what you expected?

Comment: It kept running even after it must have looped through all whereas what i want is to just loop through it ones and stop. Then the next day it will still do same thing again